# JQuery element within a certain div but ending with

Tags: asp.net, jquery

```
<div id="a">
    <select id="ctl100_placeholder1_ctl201_dpReasons"></select>

</div>

<div id="b">
     <select id="ctl100_placeholder2_ctl202_dpReasons"></select>
</div>
<div id="c">
     <select id="ctl100_placeholder3_ctl203_dpReasons"></select>
</div>
```

I am using asp.net dropdownlist which renders as above and I can get hold of the dropdown list ending with
 `$("[id$=_dpReasons]")` but how do I get it with div id ="a" or "b" or "c"

Comment: This isn't valid HTML / XHTML. The id attribute must be unique and all three of those select lists have an id="ctl100_placeholder1_ctl200_dpReasons". In reality, I imagine this isn't the case, which is why you are searching for "id ending with", but you should update your example to reflect this.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

with "a" `$("#a [id$=_dpReasons]")`
with "b" `$("#b [id$=_dpReasons]")`
with "c" `$("#c [id$=_dpReasons]")`

Answer (score 1):

This can probably be shrunk down but this will get you a combined result (see [Multiple Selector (jQuery)](http://api.jquery.com/multiple-selector/)):

```
$("#a[id$=_dpReasons],#b[id$=_dpReasons],#c[id$=_dpReasons]")
```

Comment: I had the spaces between the ID selector and the ID match selector, which would have failed, so I just fixed that.